# Convert nested XML via XQuery to flat xml

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

I've a nested piece of XML i want to insert in to SQL.

Import XML:

```
 <RECORD>
    <RECID>118810</RECID>
    <FIELD TYPE="C">
       <NAME>proj_code</NAME>
       <VALUE>118810</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD TYPE="C">
       <NAME>sub_nr</NAME>
       <VALUE>99900</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD TYPE="C">
       <NAME>proj_desc</NAME>
       <VALUE>Nagekomen kosten Oktober 2018</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD TYPE="N">
       <NAME>pro_stat</NAME>
       <VALUE>9</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD TYPE="C">
       <NAME>comment</NAME>
       <VALUE></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
</RECORD>
```

I want to convert via XQuery it into:

```
<RECORD>
    <RECID>118810</RECID>
    <proj_code>118810</proj_code>
    <sub_nr>99900</sub_nr>
    <proj_desc>Nagekomen kosten Oktober 2018</proj_desc>
    <pro_stat>9</pro_stat>
    <comment></comment>
</RECORD>
```

so i can import it into SQL.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Honnen pointed out, MS SQL Server XQuery doesn't support computed **dynamic** element names, just literals. Unfortunately, including even the latest SQL Server 2019. Here is an ugly solution.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<root>
    <RECORD>
        <RECID>118810</RECID>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>proj_code</NAME>
            <VALUE>118810</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>sub_nr</NAME>
            <VALUE>99900</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>proj_desc</NAME>
            <VALUE>Nagekomen kosten Oktober 2018</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="N">
            <NAME>pro_stat</NAME>
            <VALUE>9</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>comment</NAME>
            <VALUE></VALUE>
        </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <RECID>118811</RECID>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>proj_code</NAME>
            <VALUE>118811</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>sub_nr</NAME>
            <VALUE>99901</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>proj_desc</NAME>
            <VALUE>Nagekomen kosten November 2019</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="N">
            <NAME>pro_stat</NAME>
            <VALUE>19</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>comment</NAME>
            <VALUE>wow</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
</root>';

DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, RECID VARCHAR(10), [col_name] VARCHAR(20), [col_value] VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT c.value('(../RECID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [RECID] 
    , c.value('(NAME/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [name]
    , c.value('(VALUE/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [value]
FROM @xml.nodes('root/RECORD/FIELD') AS t(c);

DECLARE @RowCount INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @tbl)
    , @recID varchar(10) = (SELECT TOP(1) RECID FROM @tbl WHERE ID = 1)
    , @xml_data VARCHAR(MAX) = '<root><RECORD>';

WHILE @RowCount > 0 BEGIN
    SELECT @xml_data += IIF(@recID != RECID, '</RECORD><RECORD>', '') + 
        --'<' + [col_Name] + '>' + COALESCE([col_value],'') + '</' + [col_Name] + '>'
        CONCAT('<',[col_Name],'>',[col_value],'</',[col_Name],'>')
        , @recID = RECID
    FROM @tbl 
    ORDER BY ID DESC OFFSET @RowCount - 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;

    SET @RowCount -= 1;
END;

SET @xml_data += '</RECORD></root>';
SELECT CAST(@xml_data AS XML);
```

Comment: Ugly, but it works! i missed the RECID, but i added that one. Thnx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply map each `RECORD` to a new one where you map all `FIELD`s to elements with the name from NAME and the value from VALUE:

```
RECORD !
<RECORD>
{
    RECID,
    FIELD ! element { NAME } { data(VALUE) }
}    
</RECORD>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kB

For XQuery 1 you would need to use `for return` instead of the map operator `!`:

```
for $record in //RECORD
return
<RECORD>
{
    $record/RECID,
    for $field in $record/FIELD 
    return element { $field/NAME } { data($field/VALUE) }
}    
</RECORD>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kB/1

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
DECLARE @xml xml;

SET @xml =N'

    <RECORD>
        <RECID>118810</RECID>
       <FIELD TYPE="C">
          <NAME>proj_code</NAME>
          <VALUE>118810</VALUE>
       </FIELD>
       <FIELD TYPE="C">
          <NAME>sub_nr</NAME>
          <VALUE>99900</VALUE>
       </FIELD>
       <FIELD TYPE="C">
          <NAME>proj_desc</NAME>
          <VALUE>Nagekomen kosten Oktober 2018</VALUE>
       </FIELD>
       <FIELD TYPE="N">
          <NAME>pro_stat</NAME>
          <VALUE>9</VALUE>
       </FIELD>
       <FIELD TYPE="C">
          <NAME>comment</NAME>
          <VALUE></VALUE>
       </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
       <RECID>118811</RECID>
       <FIELD TYPE="C">
          <NAME>proj_code</NAME>
          <VALUE>118811</VALUE>
       </FIELD>
       <FIELD TYPE="C">
          <NAME>sub_nr</NAME>
          <VALUE>99900</VALUE>
       </FIELD>
       <FIELD TYPE="C">
          <NAME>proj_desc</NAME>
          <VALUE>Nagekomen kosten November 2018</VALUE>
       </FIELD>
       <FIELD TYPE="N">
          <NAME>pro_stat</NAME>
          <VALUE>9</VALUE>
       </FIELD>
       <FIELD TYPE="C">
          <NAME>comment</NAME>
          <VALUE></VALUE>
       </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    ';

SELECT @xml.query('
    for $record in //RECORD
    return
    <RECORD>
    {
    $record/RECID,
    for $field in $record/FIELD 
       return element { $field/NAME } { data($field/VALUE) }
    }    
    </RECORD>
' ) as result
```

But i get an error on the *return element* part: 
**XQuery [query()]: Only constant expressions are supported for the name expression of computed element and attribute constructors.**

Comment: That seems to be a restriction on the XQuery subset your database system (MS SQL server?) imposes. Let's see whether others can help in that area, if there is a tag dedicated to your database system and/or its XQuery support add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the final version with select for inserting it into SQL:**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'
<AVXML>
    <SIGNONMSGRS>
        <DTSERVER>2019-09-10T15:54:32</DTSERVER>
        <APPID>ACCOUNTVIEW</APPID>
        <APPVER>0908-</APPVER>
    </SIGNONMSGRS>  
   <EBUSMSGSRS>
      <EBUSQRYRS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <RECID>118810</RECID>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>proj_code</NAME>
            <VALUE>118810</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>sub_nr</NAME>
            <VALUE>99900</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>proj_desc</NAME>
            <VALUE>Nagekomen kosten Oktober 2018</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="N">
            <NAME>pro_stat</NAME>
            <VALUE>9</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>comment</NAME>
            <VALUE></VALUE>
        </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <RECID>118811</RECID>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>proj_code</NAME>
            <VALUE>118811</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>sub_nr</NAME>
            <VALUE>99901</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>proj_desc</NAME>
            <VALUE>Nagekomen kosten November 2019</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="N">
            <NAME>pro_stat</NAME>
            <VALUE>19</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD TYPE="C">
            <NAME>comment</NAME>
            <VALUE>wow</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
      </EBUSQRYRS>
   </EBUSMSGSRS>
</AVXML>
';

DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, RECID VARCHAR(10), [col_name] VARCHAR(20), [col_value] VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT c.value('(../RECID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [RECID] 
    , c.value('(NAME/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [name]
    , c.value('(VALUE/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(500)') AS [value]
FROM @xml.nodes('//RECORD/FIELD') AS t(c);

DECLARE @RowCount INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @tbl)
    , @recID varchar(10) = (SELECT TOP(1) RECID FROM @tbl WHERE ID = 1)
    , @xml_data VARCHAR(MAX) = '<root><RECORD>';

WHILE @RowCount > 0 BEGIN

    SELECT @xml_data += 
    IIF(@recID != RECID, 
       '<RECID>' + @recID + '</RECID>' +
       '</RECORD><RECORD>', 
       '') + 

        CONCAT('<',[col_Name],'>',[col_value],'</',[col_Name],'>')
        , @recID = RECID
    FROM @tbl 
    ORDER BY ID DESC OFFSET @RowCount - 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;

    SET @RowCount -= 1;
END;

SET @xml_data += '<RECID>' + @recID + '</RECID>' + '</RECORD></root>';

DECLARE @handler int;

exec sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @handler OUTPUT, @xml_data;
--print @xml_data

select *
from OPENXML(@handler,'/root/RECORD',11)
WITH
(   
    id nvarchar(50) 'RECID',
    proj_code nvarchar(50) 'proj_code',
    sub_nr nvarchar(50) 'sub_nr',
    proj_desc nvarchar(1000) 'proj_desc',
    pro_stat nvarchar(50) 'pro_stat',
    comment nvarchar(50) 'comment'
)
exec sys.sp_xml_removedocument @handler
```